# Use NETLink to call C# code that uses packages from nuget

Tags: .netlink

I can successfully load and run methods of a static class I have written in c# using:

```
Needs["`NETLink"];
ReinstallNET[
 "MonoPath" -> 
  "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/mono",\
 "Force32Bit" -> True];
LoadNETAssembly["/path/to/library.dll"];
LoadNETType["Namespace.StaticClassName"];
NameSpace`StaticClassName`Method[Arguments];
```

However if my library (library.dll) uses any packages from nuget then I get the following error on the last line (in this example I am trying to use Newtonsoft.Json package - but I have tried others with the same result):

```
"A .NET exception occurred: \!\(\"System.IO.FileNotFoundException: \
Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, \
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its \
dependencies.\\\\nFile name: 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, \
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'\\\\n  at (wrapper \
managed-to-native) \
System.Reflection.MonoMethod.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.\
MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)\\\\n  at \
System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, \
System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder \
binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo \
culture) [0x0003b] in <98fac219bd4e453693d76fda7bd96ab0>:0 \"\)."
```

The library compiles fine and I can use the library functions from other C# code without any issues. What am I doing wrong? I am on OSX if that is relevant.

Comment: My static class in windows system works very well. I can access the static method without problem.